# Views get corrupt when NSWindow goes to Full-screen (window's min-size violated by animation)

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, fullscreen, nswindow

My main NSWindow contains UI restricted to some size range, otherwise it can get corrupt. I restrict the window to a size-range using

[myWindow setContentsMaxSize:maxSize]
[myWindow setContentsMinSize:minSize]

This works fine for user dragging of the edges or size-box.

When the user presses "fullscreen" button, Lion starts an animation that will

1. Shrink the window below its current size,
2. in several steps, increase its size until it reaches the full-screen representation size.

If the window started in its minimal size, this animation will shrink it BELOW the defined minimal size, and will corrupt my UI beyond repair (user needs to relaunch the app). My views are receiving setFrameSize: with unsupported size.

My questions

- Can this be considered a Cocoa bug?
- Am I doing something wrong in my view hierarchy?
- Can I somehow prevent the corruption, without replacing the OS standard animation for full-screen?
- Why doesn't the standard animation base on a "snapshot" of the window contents, instead of
  live-resizing of the whole view-hierarchy throughout the animation? This is surely not efficient.
- Is there a simple way to apply another standard transition that will
  be non-destructive for me?
- Can someone "spare" a few lines of code that will do a simple linear resizing animation that will NOT go below minimum?

Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

I've also investigated **fullscreen animation behaviour and here is how it works:**

It is also based on taking snapshots of window's content, but with some improvements. It takes several snapshots on some control points: 512, 1024, 2048 and so on.
In my case to enter full screen 2560x1440, my 400 pixels wide window took 512 pixels snapshot, then 1024 and then 2560 wide snapshot. I don't know whether this behaviour is default for all cases, but this is the result of my own investigation.

On the issue with **setting min/max window size:**
Minimal window size set up in Interface Builder works for me, but max constraints not. I'm currently working on it and this documented method should work for you:

Place this code into your window delegate.

```
static const NSSize kWindowMinSize = {100, 100};
static const NSSize kWindowMaxSize = {100500, 100500};

...

- (NSSize)windowWillResize:(NSWindow *)sender toSize:(NSSize)frameSize
{
    frameSize.width = MAX(kWindowMinSize.width, MIN(kWindowMaxSize.width, frameSize.width));
    frameSize.height = MAX(kWindowMinSize.height, MIN(kWindowMaxSize.height, frameSize.height));
    return frameSize;
}
```

Hope this will help you!